# targeting a specific form with serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

Following on [from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592669/building-value-of-a-variable-by-looping-through-form-fields), which was [so quickly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592669/building-value-of-a-variable-by-looping-through-form-fields/1592673#1592673) by [Meder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145190/meder) it wasn't funny, there's now an additional question that's popped up in the process of making a reusable jQuery form submitted that doesn't take the user away from where they were.

**Problem**

The jQuery `serialize()` function is performing its magic on all forms within a page, and not the specific form which was submitted. Example code below.

How do I capture the form's unique name/id, and replace `"form"` within `$("form").serialize()` with the name of the target form so only that is serialised?

**Form code**

```
<form name="contact" id="contact" action="">
  <input name="_recipients" type="hidden" value="joe@fake.com" />
  <input name="_subject" type="hidden" value="Title" />
  ...
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label><br />

      <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label><br />

      <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label><br/>

        <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send your suggestion" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

**jQuery serialise and post**

```
    var dataString = $("form").serialize();
    //alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/_global/assets/scripts/formmail/formmail.asp",
      data: dataString,
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dataString = $('#contact').serialize()
```

If you are attaching an event handler to a button or the form's `submit` event then you can refer to it with `this` if inside the `submit` event handler function scope, eg

```
$('#contact').submit(function() {
 alert( $(this).serialize() );
});
```

I highly recommend reading http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however my whole point of this is not having to specify the name of the field in the actual code - otherwise has to be changed each time it is reused. Needing to detect the name of the form being passed and adding this in-place of form programatically.

Comment: Did you see my second code snippet regarding setting up a submit event handler? You dont have to specify if you use the `this` keyword in the correct function scope/context.

Comment: You can do something more generical like `$('form.validate').submit(function(){})` and then use `this` inside to refer to the form.

Comment: Thank you, I will now eat my own words and must once again bow to your immense expeirence.

Check out the sample link above, makes it pretty clear what needs to be done.

Summary, apply a unique class to the form, detect for this class when submit button is activated, and tell serialize() only to process data for the form in question.

Answer (score 3):

By using the "form" string as a selector, you are actually getting all the `FORM` elements within the page, in order to select only one form, you can:

Get the specific form by its id attribute (using the [id selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id)):

```
var dataString = $("#contact").serialize();
```

Or by its name attribute (using the [attributeEquals](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals) selector):

```
var dataString = $("form[name=contact]").serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however my whole point of this is not having to specify the name of the field in the actual code - otherwise has to be changed each time it is reused. Needing to detect the name of the form being passed and adding this in-place of form programatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#contact").serialize()
```

Instead of using `serialize` there's a nice [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) that allows you to post your forms asynchronously. All you have to do is:

```
$(function() {)
    $('#contact').ajaxForm(); 
});
```

Also don't forget to assign the correct action to the form, it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however my whole point of this is not having to specify the name of the field in the actual code - otherwise has to be changed each time it is reused. Needing to detect the name of the form being passed and adding this in-place of form programatically.